# Storybook Mock GraphQL (Gatsby)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, storybook

I am using Gatsby to create a blog. Gatsby can use markdown with GraphQL to "automagically" create post pages for you. I was wondering using the [Gatsby example here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/).

In storybook UI what is the best way to "mock" out the graphql query and replace it with our markdown data. So that I can test this component in Storybook UI. For example if I have a blog template that looks something like:

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import React from 'react';

export default function Template({
  data, // this prop will be injected by the GraphQL query below.
}) {
  const { markdownRemark } = data; // data.markdownRemark holds your post data
  const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark;
  return (
    <div className="blog-post-container">
      <div className="blog-post">
        <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <h2>{frontmatter.date}</h2>
        <div
          className="blog-post-content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        slug
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably modify [the webpack configuration of Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) to use the [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) to mock the whole `gatsby` package. Then export a `graphql` method from your mock that you can manipulate in your stories.

Alternatively, split your component into a pure component and a component that performs the query and just use the pure component as suggested in https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/unit-testing/